# submit country by ISO code - html form

Tags: html, forms

So i would like to offer a list of all countries for a user to select from a form. I found a pretty good [list of countries](http://www.freeformatter.com/iso-country-list-html-select.html) in html format from this site. The site implements my task by listing out the full country name as an html string but the form actually sends its ISO code to the server. This is great but how would someone tackle the issue of presenting the full country name when reading the submitted values?

Do you think its best to submit a country value as ISO values or should I just submit the full name name of the country? All sites seem to be doing the earlier option but it just seems like a hassle to me. Can someone present some thoughts to this matter explaining why to use ISO codes in the first place and how to decode them back to country names if their ISO were used? thank you

Comment: You could create a javascript reference array...  That's what I would do.

Comment: but why use the ISO code rather than the raw country name? why are people doing this?

Comment: @alboudi, I think it's more common than you think.  There are number of reasons that a short code is desirable over saving the entire country name.  Database space, for one thing.

Comment: To make it simpler, i'd just send the exact data you need, whether it's the ISO value or full country name.  Obviously, the less data you're sending and storing, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment...  The idea is, when the select changes, it calls the JS function.  In there, you have an array set up with the key matching the value of the select, and what you want it to show.  So, you'd just need to pass that code the array to get the value.

```
<form>

<select onchange="showName()" id="country">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
...
</select>
<div id="selResult">
selected: nothing
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var myArray = {"AF": "Afghanistan", "AX": "Åland Islands", "AL": "Albania"};
function showName(){
  selectRes = myArray[document.getElementById("country").value];
  document.getElementById("selResult").innerHTML = selectRes;
}
```

You'll have to create the complete list.  But that's the basic idea how to make it work.

This [here fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durbnpoisn/o7krkqm3/) has this whole thing, plus one additional way to make use of the reference array.

For what it's worth, if you intend to use this a lot, you should consider creating a reference table in your database, rather than mucking around in JS to do this.

Comment: thank you for showing me a JS implementation of this. Id also appreciate it if you could answer the second component of my question. Why should someone use ISO codes in the first place? What is the rationale behind doing so?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons.  The least of which would be that the code is universal.  The spelling of the country, maybe not.  Database space.  More characters means more data.  Also, when it comes time to organize output later, 2 characters takes up less space on a table, and keeps everything uniform.